# How to remove space in bottom webview When change size text in webview with seekbar

Tags: android

I used seekbar to change size text in webview , but when I increase font size text and after I decrease  font size, my webview have space in bottom
How I can remove it?
My code

```html
final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
String content =<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width="
                                                            + 480+ "\"><style type='text/css'>@font-face {
 font-family: MyFont;
src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/FontContent.otf")
  }
 body {
 font-family: MyFont;
 font-size: medium;
 text-align: justify;
   height: 100%;
  }.top { vertical-align: top; } img{ width: 100%;} div{margin-top: 10px; clear: both;} table{max-width: 100%;} </style></head><script type="text/javascript">function showAndroidToast(toast) {Android.showToast(toast);}document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
var width = document.getElementById("img").width;    document.getElementById("img").style.height = width+'px';
  });</script><body style='font-family: MyFont; clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0;'><p style='color: #C1C1C1;margin-left: 7px;'>19:30 02-03-2016</p><h2 style='text-align: left;margin-right: 7px; margin-left: 7px;'>Apple iPad 9,7 inch kế tiếp sẽ là “biến thể” của iPad Pro</h2><div style=" margin-right:7px; margin-left:7px;" >
   <h3 style ='text-align: justify;'>Thông tin này đã hoàn toàn phủ định các tin đồn cho rằng iPad Pro sắp tới sẽ có thông số kỹ thuật tương đương như Pro 2. </h3>
  </div><i><p style='float: right; color: #f58634; margin-right: 7px;'>THEO DANVIET</p></i></body>
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content,
   mimeType, encoding, "");
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int size = 0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                size = progress;
                ws.setDefaultFontSize(size);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                ws.setDefaultFontSize(size);
                SendTracker.sendTrackerEvent(mTracker, "Bài viết", "Thay đổi font size", String.valueOf(size));
            }
        });
```

and my xml file

```html
   <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wvContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></WebView>
```

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot so everyone can see exactly the problem.